# $.ajax autocomplete not working in ie 11 in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coming to a problem where my autocomplete code below works on chrome and firefox, but not internet explorer 11. Can anyone help me solve my code. I think its `$.ajax` problem that ie not supporting, but can anyone help me with my code below. thanks.

```js
$("#searchTextField").autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  source: myData,
  select: function select(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = '#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml';
    var searchValue = ui.item.value;
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('searchValue', searchValue);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      method: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
    }).done(text => {
      $('#results').append($(text).find('#textTable'));
      $('#results').append($(text).find('table'));
      $('#results').append($(text).find('#bestTable'));
      $("#clearone").show();
    });
  },
  response: function response(event, ui,) {
    if (!ui.content.length) {
      var message = {
        value: "",
        label: "NOTHING FOUND"
      };
      ui.content.push(message);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of reasons this won't work in IE. Firstly you have a trailing comma in the `response` handler function which needs to be removed:

```
response: function response(event, ui,) {
```

Secondly you're using an arrow function in `done()`; these are completely unsupported in any version of IE.

```
$.ajax({ /* ... */ }).done(text => {
```

Use a traditional anonymous function instead. Here's a full example with these fixes:

```js
$("#searchTextField").autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  source: myData,
  select: function select(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = '#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml';
    var searchValue = ui.item.value;
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('searchValue', searchValue);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      method: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
    }).done(function(text) {
      $('#results').append($(text).find('#textTable'));
      $('#results').append($(text).find('table'));
      $('#results').append($(text).find('#bestTable'));
      $("#clearone").show();
    });
  },
  response: function response(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.content.length) {
      var message = {
        value: "",
        label: "NOTHING FOUND"
      };
      ui.content.push(message);
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, note that you can debug JS issues like this by using the developer tools (press F12 to open them in most browsers) and viewing the errors in the console.